# Why my "let" variable does not clear the input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The input field doest not reset when "let" is used but it resets when form.number.value is used

```
<!-- HTML CODE  -->
<form action="" class="form">
    <input type="number" id="number">
    <input type="submit" name="" id="btn">
</form>

<!-- JS CODE  -->
const form = document.querySelector('.form');

form.addEventListener('submit' , e=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    let inNumber = form.number.value;

    let randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * inNumber);
    console.log(randomNumber);
    inNumber = '';
})
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't work like this. You have to manually clear the input field value.

Comment: If you have `let o = {p: 1}` and let `x = o.p`, executing `x = 2`, does not update `o.p` only `x` because the statement `x = o.p` simply creates a reference to whatever `o.p` itself refers to.

Comment: Okay now i get it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not allowed to comment yet, here's what I noticed-
If we set `inNumber = form.number` then `inNumber.value = ""` resets `form.number.value`.
But `inNumber = form.number.value` doesn't perform the reset job with `inNumber = ""`.
Anybody knows the reason?

Comment: Because, in your example, `inNumber` is set to `form.number`, it is an alias for whatever `form.number` is at the time of assignment.

Comment: oh I just missed that!

Comment: More specifically, `inNumber` is an alias for whatever `form.number` is when it is initialized, if `form.number` changed to refer to some other input, like if we did `form.number = form.email`, then `inNumber` would still refer to whatever `form.number` referred to when `inNumber` was initialized.

Comment: so ````inNumber = form.number````  means ````inNumber = $(".form").number```` i.e. it refers to the ````number````object in  ````form```` element that it queries from DOM. but ````inNumber = form.number.value```` refers to just a number value that it seems to copy to ````inNumber````. Right? if you could clarify again?

Comment: Basically. A few differences: 1) jQuery ($) is not involved or relevant. 2) `form.number.value` is actually a string because of how HTML is. 3) given `inNumber = form.number.value`, `inNumber` is indeed a copy, but the point is that it is the _value_ of the `form.number.value` property, not the property _itself_.

Comment: It is worth noting that there are languages that allow you to create variables that are actually references to other variables and to properties, but that JavaScript is not one of them. See C++, C#, Rust, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `form.number.value` is a getter

`let inNumber = form.number.value;` this will give you the value not the setter i.e. not by reference.
So doing `isNumber = '';` will only change the value of `isNumber` not of `form.number.value`

And when you do `form.number.value = ''` it's a setter, hence it works.

Reference: [w3schools - form.input.value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

Comment: It is both readable and writable. JavaScript doesn't have by-reference semantics and setters don't have anything to do with that.

Answer (score -1):

`numbers` are essentially copy-by-value when assigned to a variable. Which means the variable holds a copy of the value not a pointer to the forms value.

Later when you do

```
inNumber = '';
```

You are simply setting the variables value. You need to set the forms value to reset it:

```
form.number.value = '';
```

Alternately you can make a *reference* to the object holding the value

```
let inNumber = form.number;
// ...
inNumber.value = '';
```

Comment: This is false. While you have the correct solution, your explanation is completely wrong. It has nothing to do with its being a `number`. If `this.form.value` were not a number, the behavior would be identical.

Comment: In order to modify change the value of one of an object's properties, you need a reference to that object, but it has nothing to do with the type of the object in question.

Comment: It is correct, Aluan is wrong. I didn't say other values wouldn't also copy by value and I did show an example of copying the object the value is on.

Comment: Everything is by value, but you suggest otherwise. Moreover, that isn't why the code in the OP was not working: Given `var a = {b: {c: 1}}, x = a.b;`, `x` and `a.b` are both pointers to the same object, but setting `x = {}` won't update `a.b`, but rather create an object and make make `x` point to it. This is because `x` is a copy, as you say, of the pointer `a.b`. I realize you understand this, but your answer suggests the issue is based on some distinction between different types of values when it actually has to do something else.

Answer (score -1):

You can use two way to `reset` form by, html element in this case not two way bind with variable

```
isNumber = ''
form.number.value = isNumber;
```

or use

```
form.reset();
```

```js
<!-- JS CODE  -->
const form = document.querySelector('.form');

form.addEventListener('submit' , e=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    let inNumber = form.number.value;

    let randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * inNumber);
    console.log(randomNumber);
    isNumber = ''
    form.number.value = isNumber;
    //form.reset();
})
```

```html
<!-- HTML CODE  -->
<form action="" class="form">
    <input type="number" id="number">
    <input type="submit" name="" id="btn">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this happens?

Comment: inNumber only get value from input, you need set it again to input, i updated answer

Comment: This has nothing to do with databinding, or HTML to JS interaction. It is purely a question of JavaScript language semantics.